# Is it possible in Sublime Text to navigate from keyboard to a file in search results?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Let's say I searched for `a promise chain` text in Sublime Text.
I will see the following result

[image: sublime text]

Now, I can either double click (via mouse) the filename (in yellow) to navigate to the file, or double click the highlighted snippet, to navigate directly to that snippet in the file.

Is there a **keybinding** to do the same without the need for a mouse?

Comment: There is no built in keybinding, but it should be possible to create one... The `command` is `drag_select`, and it needs the following arguments `{"by": "words", "event": {"button": 1, "x": 448.5, "y": 90.5}}`, where x and y are the mouse co-ordinates to the cursor/selection position... Unfortunately [the API reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View) shows that although you can get the layout co-ordinates from the text position (using `text_to_layout`), there is no way to translate it to window co-ordinates, which seems to be what it needs...